# how to create code for as below result?

Tags: python

```
def number_of_cases(list_data):
    from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
    mylist = list_data
    result = list(combinations_with_replacement(mylist, 2))
    return(result)

def main():
    result = number_of_cases(['a', 'b'])
    print(result)
```

result:

```
>>> main()
[('a', 'a'), ('a', 'b'), ('b', 'b')]
```

I don't want any space between combination... as below..
       how to create code for as below results?

```
>>> a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
['aa', 'ab', 'ac', 'ba', 'bb', 'bc', 'ca', 'cb', 'cc']'

>>> a = ['a', 'a']
['aa']

>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 'a']
['11', '12', '13', '1a', '21', '22', '23', '2a', '31', '32', '33', '3a', 'a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'aa']
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to str() the elements to get them all as strings, and then just join each element of the result list.

```
def number_of_cases(list_data):
     from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
     list_data = [str(data) for data in list_data]
     mylist=list_data
     result=list(combinations_with_replacement(mylist,2))
     joined_result = []
     for choice in result:
           joined = ''.join(choice)
           joined_result.append(joined)
     return(joined_result)

def main():
     result=number_of_cases(['a','b'])
     print(result)
```

['aa', 'ab', 'bb']

Comment: This does not work when one or more go the elements is an integer, rather than a char, as in one of the examples.

Comment: Fixed now. 5char